# PubNub functions not working when sending messages to a particular channel in a group channel?

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

I have created a function on PubNub dashboard and assigned the channel name as group channel name. This is not being called when I publish message to specific channel instead of channel group.

Here is the function written on console. 
[image]

My publish message code is

```
func publishMessage(text : String) {
    if text != "" {
        let currentTimeMilliSec = System.currentTimeInMilliSeconds()
        clientIdentifier?.publish(["messageText": text, "senderID" : UserDefaultsSettings.getLoggedInUserMobNo()!, "createdAt" : currentTimeMilliSec, "channelName" : self.subChannel], toChannel: self.subChannel, withMetadata: ["channelName" : self.subChannel], completion: { (status) in
            if !status.isError {
                // Message successfully published to specified channel.
            } else {
                /**
                 Handle message publish error. Check 'category' property to find
                 out possible reason because of which request did fail.
                 */
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi!  Thank you for asking.  This looks like you are doing things correctly and just one part is unconnected.  Clarifying a few things first: channel groups are usable only for subscriptions.  So your swift iOS app will be able to subscribe to a channel group.  However you can not Publish to a channel group.  You can publish to individual channels only.  Publishing to an individual channel with an On-Before Function running will be processed and received by a subscriber to that individual channel or if the subscriber is subscribing to the channel group where that channel has been added.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a Channel Group's name as the Channel name on which to execute the function. You can use either a single channel's name to execute the function or use wildcards `root.*` to set a *range of channels* to run the function.

Let me know if you need further info on that.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Please elaborate,  what is "root" in wildcards "root.*" 
@Paras

Comment: @Harish basically you can set a channel's name up to 3 levels deep. E.g. a channel name could be "ch1" or "ch1.some" or "ch1.some.thing" Of course, you can replace "ch1", "some" and "thing" with anything you like as they are just placeholders to help describe channel naming conventions. When you have multi-level deep channel names, and more than 1 channel share the same prefix like "ch1.abc" and "ch1."def" you can choose to execute the PubNub Function for "ch1.*" based channels by setting "ch1.*" as the channel to run the function on.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks @Paras

Answer (score 0):

**According to your account records**, you are publishing `{"text":"Fine"}` and your function code needs to use this field format:

```
let text = request.message.text;
request.message.text = text.replace( /E/g, '' );
request.message.text = insert( request.message.text, 4, 'E' );
```

<strike>request.message.messageText</strike>